# What do we call a metric that doesn't satisfy triangle inequality?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

According to wikipedia a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) is a function $d(x,y)$ that satisfies

- non-negativity
- identity of indiscernibles
- symmetry
- triangle inequality

What should we call $d(x,y)$ if the triangle inequality (and probably identity of indiscernibles) doesn't hold?
For example $d(x,y)=x^2+y^2-3xy$?

Comment: A “mec”? ($\mathrm{metric} - \mathrm{tri}$)

Comment: @user1892304 good job!

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Semimetrizable spaces are characterized by having a base $\{B(x,n):\langle x,n\rangle\in X\times\Bbb N\}$ such that $y\in B(x,n)$ iff $x\in B(y,n)$; it’s been many years since I dealt with such things, and I no longer remember any specific examples, but I seem to recall that this combination of first countability and symmetry is enough to substitute for metrizability in some theorems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called a [semimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Semimetrics) according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Not just Wikipedia: that’s the term that I learned some forty-five years ago, and it’s the term used in Willard’s *General Topology* (Exercise $23$F).